# Verbs of perception: see, hear, watch + object +[bare infinitive/ gerund/ adjective/ past participle/]

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, verbs-of-perception

Some of the verbs called "verbs of perception or perceptual. However many English language learners would face many problems with using them, me one of them.

>

Some of them are being used in such as the following basis (***active*** ***form***):
 - {see/look/watch/notice/observe/hear} + object +  {gerunds/bare infinitive}.

> But sometimes, issues are made with passive form. 
>   Is the following rule is right or wrong? Correct it if is wrong. 
>    - {see/watch, etc.} + object + {adjective/ past participle}
>
> Or:
>
> - {see/watch, etc.} + object (being: optional or required?) + {adjective/ past participle}.

>
>

> - I saw a person repairing my car. (Active form)
> - I saw a person repair my car. (Active form)
> - I saw a car being repaired. (Passive form)
> - I saw a car repaired. (Passive form)
> - I saw a car be repaired. (Passive form)
> - I watched a man solve the problem. (Active form)
> - I watched a man solving the problem. (Active form)
> - I watched a problem be solved . (Passive form)
> - I watched a problem being solved. (Passive form)
> - I watched a problem solved. (Passive form)
>
> I am confused about which sentences are wrong and which ones are right?
>
> Could just explain deeply, and elaborate on demonstrations of each one of these examples?

Answer (score 0):

The **active voice** is speech that places the **subject first**, followed by a verb, and a place/object. Therefore the correct form is subject -- verb -- object.

The **passive voice** is speech that places the **object first**, followed by a verb (tense and a gerund), and the subject. Therefore the correct form is object -- verb -- subject.

None of these sentences are in the passive voice, since *I* (the subject), always comes first in each of them.

Most of these can be converted from **active voice** to *passive voice*:

> **I saw a person repairing my car.** *The car was being repaired by someone.*
>
> **I saw a person repair my car.** *The car was repaired by someone.*
>
> **I saw a car being repaired.** / **I saw a car be repaired.** *A car was being repaired.*
>
> **I watched a man solve the problem.** *The problem was solved by a man.*
>
> **I watched a man solving the problem.** *The problem was being solved by a man.*
>
> **I watched a problem being solved.** / **I watched a problem be solved.** *The problem was being solved.*

Notice that none of these use *I*, mainly because I couldn't find a logical incorporation. I suppose you could say (and use as a guideline):

> The car was being repaired by someone **I was watching**.
>
> The problem was solved **as I watched.**

The sentences *I saw a car repaired* and *I saw a problem solved* don't make sense to me because the past participle is just by itself. I would include words to tie it together with everything else:

> I saw a car **that was** repaired.
>
> I saw a car **that had been** repaired.
>
> I saw a problem **that was** solved.
>
> I saw a problem **that had been** solved.

I also think that adding a comma, though strange, is acceptable:

> I saw a car, repaired.
>
> I saw a problem, solved.